# how to find the relationship which makes two variables cointegrated by engle granger test, in python python

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

Using statsmodels.tsa.stattools.coint in python to test for cointegration, you input vector Y and vector X to test for cointegration using augemented engle-granger test. It returns a p-value for the significance of the test.

Cointegrated variables are two variables X and Y such that X-aY = c + e, where a is a constant, c is a constant and e is a stationary process. So X-aY will be a stationary process.

First question is, when inputting Y and X into the statsmodels.tsa.stattools.coint function, do I input the raw/untransformed Y and X vectors, or do I input the aY and X vectors?

I'm assuming from reading the documentation that its the raw/untransformed values. In that case, how do I get the constants a and c such that X-aY = c + e? Even after (or before) testing for cointegration, I need to know the relationship between them which makes them cointegrated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little biased, but I'll show you how you can perform CI analysis using the `arch` package (that I maintain)

```
import numpy as np
from arch.unitroot import engle_granger

rg = np.random.default_rng(20210215)
x = np.cumsum(rg.standard_normal(250))
y = 7 + 0.5*x + rg.standard_normal(250)

res = engle_granger(y,x)
# Print the summary
print(res.summary())
# Print the CI vector
print(res.cointegrating_vector)
```

The prints

```
     Engle-Granger Cointegration Test
=========================================
Test Statistic                    -15.393
P-value                             0.000
ADF Lag length                          0
Estimated Root ρ (γ+1)              0.022
-----------------------------------------

Trend: Constant
Critical Values: -3.07 (10%), -3.37 (5%), -3.95 (1%)
Null Hypothesis: No Cointegration
Alternative Hypothesis: Cointegration
Distribution Order: 1
```

and the CI vector

```
y        1.000000
x1      -0.507630
const   -6.883263
dtype: float64
```

so that the error is `y + res.cointegrating_vector["const"]  + res.cointegrating_vector["x1"] * x`